# iOS local notifications background

Tags: ios, parsing, notifications, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I've done an application that parse some data from an extern server that is not mine.
I would like to send a notification to the user every time the server modifies a value but I don't know if I have to create another server to allow push notifications or if there is a way to implement this via Local notifications.

Comment: If you want to send on server event - push notification is the way to go. Local notifications are only useful when you know that something will happen at exact date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the background refresh (available from iOS7) to pull data. There you may schedule a `UILocalNotification` to notify the user about new data.
Note that iOS decides when to do the update, i.e. it is not necessarily after each update on the server.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new on iOS7 ;)